# Error when creating a new Type in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

What is the cause of getting this error when creating a new Type in SQL Developer?

> 2/1 PLS-00103: "CREATE" symbol encountered Errors: consult the
>   compiler log

### EDIT (from comment)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE hypotheses AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(5);
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE focal_element AS
  OBJECT (focal_element_content hypotheses,
          focal_element_mass NUMBER);
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE bba AS TABLE OF focal_element;
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE confidence_level AS
  OBJECT(bel NUMBER,
         pl NUMBER);
```

Comment: Post your code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it, your code is **almost perfect**. A tiny slash is missing (OK, a few of them).

This is what you did:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE hypotheses AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(5);
  2  CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE focal_element AS
  3    OBJECT (focal_element_content hypotheses,
  4            focal_element_mass NUMBER);
  5  CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE bba AS TABLE OF focal_element;
  6  CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE confidence_level AS
  7    OBJECT(bel NUMBER,
  8           pl NUMBER);
  9  /

Warning: Type created with compilation errors.

SQL> SHOW ERR
Errors for TYPE HYPOTHESES:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
2/1      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE"
```

This is what you should have done: terminated each `CREATE TYPE` with a slash:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE hypotheses AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(5);
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE focal_element AS
  2    OBJECT (focal_element_content hypotheses,
  3            focal_element_mass NUMBER);
  4  /

Type created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE bba AS TABLE OF focal_element;
  2  /

Type created.

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE confidence_level AS
  2    OBJECT(bel NUMBER,
  3           pl NUMBER);
  4  /

Type created.

SQL>
```

Better, is it not?

**[EDIT]**

Saying that you can't make it work in SQL Developer: well, I can, so - looks like PEBKAC.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's great. But he/she is trying to execute the code from SQL Developer so this will only cause more confusion I think.

Comment: I'm not implying that your solution is wrong. In other cases it will be really great. But in this case the solution might be simpler :)

Comment: @Littelefoot Even with the / it does not work because I worked on SQLDeveloper and so it showed me an error.

Comment: I attached an image which shows that it *works* in SQL Developer.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell from your post, but based on the error message (`PLS-00103`) it appears that you're attempting to execute these `CREATE` statements in a PL/SQL block. PL/SQL does not allow CREATE statements to be executed directly - instead, you need to use an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement:

```
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE hypotheses AS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(5)';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE focal_element AS ' ||
                       'OBJECT (focal_element_content hypotheses, ' ||
                               'focal_element_mass NUMBER)';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE bba AS TABLE OF focal_element';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE confidence_level AS ' ||
                       'OBJECT(bel NUMBER, ' ||
                              'pl NUMBER)';
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution apart from @Bob Jarvis' solution can be, since you are using SQL Developer, run each `CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE` at a time.

Select all of the first statement and then run (by clicking run button or by clicking `CTRL + ENTER`).

And so on with each line of your code.